# Routes in rails 4 with clean parameters in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

How does routing work in rails 4? What I'm trying to achieve is urls like this:

```
..../categories/<name of category>
```

when currently i get:

```
..../categories?utf8=✓&category=dingus
```

html is:

```
<%= form_tag(categories_path, :method => "get") do %>
   <%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(@categories, params[:category]), {onchange: "this.form.submit();", prompt: "Select Category"} %>
<% end %>
```

and routes like this:

```
 get '/' => '<controller>#h'
 get 'categories' => '<controller>#categories'
```

I know i can use the gem friendly_id to style the url from category/:id to category/:category. But I'm stuck at the initial step of understanding the routes. I've tried a lot of things but its very confusing. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), specifically the section on Resources.

If you had in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :categories
```

You could use a form helper such as:

```
<%= form_tag(categories_path, :method => "get") do %>
   <%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(@categories.map {|c| [c.name, category_path(c)]}, params[:category]), {onchange: "window.location.href = this.value;", prompt: "Select Category"} %>
<% end %>
```

If in your `Category` model you added a `to_param` definition:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

Then all of your URLs would be as you desire, `.../categories/books`. The `url_for` helpers would generate the appropriate URLs for you:

```
assert category_path(@book_category) == "/categories/book"
```

See [ActiveRecords::Integrations#to_param](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Integration.html#method-i-to_param) documentation for more.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Sam's exact solution to work. My `@categories` is derived array of unique categories in Post model:

```
@categories = Post.pluck(:category).uniq
```

so with a little change it works like:

erb:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
    <%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(@categories.map {|c| [c, show_category_path(c)]}, params[:category]), {onchange: "window.location.href = this.value;", prompt: "Select Category"} %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
get '/categories/:category' => 'posts#categories', as: 'show_category'
```

controller

```
def categories
    @posts = Post.where(category: params[:category])
end
```

So URL is: `/categories/dingus`. I have problem with spaces being shown as %20 now (e.g. `/categories/dingus%20burger`, but that is another matter and i suspect the to_param or url_for methods will help that that

This tutorial was very helpful for me to understand routes a little better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16Bk_0RADLQ